# Apache Beam running Pipeline from DoFn throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, nosuchmethoderror

I am running an Application on Google AppEngine which generates Dataflow-Templates and starts them. In one of those pipelines, inside a DoFn, the process generates another pipeline and waits for it to finish, before it continues its work. Until a few days ago, that was not a problem. But now, I get a NoSuchMethodError when pipeline.run() is called.

The stacktrace:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.beam.sdk.common.runner.v1.RunnerApi$FunctionSpec$Builder.setPayload(Lcom/google/protobuf/ByteString;)Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/common/runner/v1/RunnerApi$FunctionSpec$Builder;
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.WindowingStrategyTranslation.toProto(WindowingStrategyTranslation.java:224)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.WindowingStrategyTranslation.toProto(WindowingStrategyTranslation.java:299)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.WindowingStrategyTranslation.toProto(WindowingStrategyTranslation.java:285)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator.serializeWindowingStrategy(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:129)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator.access$1500(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:114)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$5.groupByKeyHelper(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:806)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$5.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:784)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$5.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:781)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.visitPrimitiveTransform(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:442)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:663)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:655)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:655)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:655)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:655)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:655)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:311)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:245)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:446)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:386)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:173)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:537)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:170)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:303)
>       at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:289)
>       at com.mycompany.projectsign.dataflow.dofn.downloads.something.RunDownloadPipeline.processElement(RunDownloadPipeline.java:150)

The referenced line of my code is the pipeline.run()

When I look at the maven-dependencies in Eclipse, the right dependencies (and versions) are added in the project and the RunnerApi.FunctionSpec.Builder.setPayload(com.google.protobuf.ByteString) method exists, too. I continued enforcing the versions with dependencyManagement:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-common-runner-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        .....
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When running in AppEngine or creating the pipeline from localhost (running directly on Google Dataflow) the templates can be created and started without a problem, but running the created Pipeline inside the DoFn throws the same error.

However, when I run the Pipeline as a local pipeline directly on my computer (with DirectRunner), the pipeline runs without a problem and creates the other pipelines on GoogleDataflow.

I updated the beam-version to 2.2.0.

If some Googler is reading this, this is one of the failing JobIds: 2017-12-11_07_01_17-3122752092943950314

What might be the reason for the NoSuchMethodError? Could it be a conflicting dependency or something else?

Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: To update this question: I resigned and redesigned the process. We already had an AppEngine TaskQueue System to run and check Jobs, so I divided the process into more pipelines, as it is not time sensitive.
As a followup Question: Is there a way to easily determine which version of a dependency is effectively used at runtime?